# Why isn't my code getting the JSON values?

Tags: javascript, json

```
        function getResults(){
            var text = encodeURIComponent(searchField.val().trim());
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&format=json&titles=" + text,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function(data){
                    showResults(data, text);
                }
            });
    }

    function showResults(data, text) {
            results.show();
            var query = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + text;
            for (var id in data.query.pages) {
                    var code = "<a href=" + query + " class='results'>" + "<div class='results'>";
                    code = code + "<strong>" + id.title + "</strong>";
                    code = code + "<br>";
                    code = code + id.extract;
                    code = code + "</div></a>"
                    $(code).appendTo(results); 
            }
    }
```

In the showResults function, its showing the id.title and id.extract as undefined. Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
for (var id in data.query.pages)
```

The, `id` variable is filled with a property name which is simply a string.  If you want to get that value of that property, you have to reference the value of that property as in:

```
data.query.pages[id]
```

Or, if that's an object that you then want `.title` from, then you would need

```
data.query.pages[id].title
```

and

```
data.query.pages[id].extract
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because when iterating over an object (using `for-var-in-object` loop), the `var` (`id` in this case) is the key, but if you need value, use `object[key]` syntax. Check the following code

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exintro&format=json&titles=newton",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(data) {
    for (var id in data.query.pages)
      document.write(data.query.pages[id].title);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you are using just `key`=> '321123'. To get value of object use `key`. To get object `data.query.pages[id]`.

```
for (var id in wiki = data.query.pages){
    wiki[id].title;
    wiki[id].extract;
}
```

This one should work.

```
   function showResults(data, text) {
                results.show();
                var query = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + text;
                for (var id in wiki = data.query.pages) {
                        var code = "<a href=" + query + " class='results'>" + "<div class='results'>";
                        code = code + "<strong>" + wiki[id].title + "</strong>";
                        code = code + "<br>";
                        code = code + wiki[id].extract;
                        code = code + "</div></a>"
                        $(code).appendTo(results); 
                }
        }
```